Next.js - no warning/error by ESLint when no width/height/fill is provided as props
To start with, I encountered a run time error when using Next.js Image Component.
MyComponent.tsx
import Image from "next/image";
...
        <Image
          src={"/assets/live_view.jpg"}
          alt={"Live-View-Image"}
        />

Error Message
Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`ForwardRef`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ForwardRef`, follow the stack trace as described in ...

After providing a fill prop, the error is gone. That makes me thinking why VSCode/ESLint doesn't show an error on compiled time. I remember Next.js/ESLint will shows the error in the IDE when no such props provided from my experience on my other Next.js projects.
package.json
"next": "14.2.3",
"eslint": "8.27.0",
"eslint-config-next": "^14.2.3",

.eslintrc.json
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals"],
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  }
}


Verified ESLint works. Also tried to restart VSCode but still no luck.
How to turn on/enable the ESLint warning/errors for Next.js Image component?

Have you installed the Eslint extension in your IDE?
